# Central class for calling static methods in Data Access Layer

Tags: apex, design-patterns, static

Much like the Factory pattern I am looking for a good way to call the desired Data Access methods through a central class. Unfortunately, my DAL classes are static (as I need them to cache records) so I cannot use the Factory pattern. I don't want to convert them into Singletons either unless I see solid benefits in doing so.

In the following code `Part` is related to `Car` and `Boat` via a junction object, and `Part` has related child objects that need to be returned. This is why some of the methods return Maps:

```
public class CarDataAccess
{
    public static Car__c[] queryCars(Id[] carIds) { ... }
    public static Car__c[] queryCars(String[] uniqueIds) { ... }
    public static Map<Car__c, Part__c[]> queryAllCars(Boolean activeOnly) { ... }
}

public class BoatDataAccess
{
    public static Boat__c[] queryBoats(Id[] boatIds) { ... }
    public static Boat__c[] queryBoats(String[] uniqueIds) { ... }
    public static Map<Boat__c, Part__c[]> queryAllBoats(Boolean activeOnly) { ... }
}

/*  The Part object has no Unique Id or Active field  */
public class PartDataAccess
{
    public static Part__c[] queryParts(Id[] partIds) { ... }
    public static Part__c[] queryAllParts() { ... }
}
```

What I currently have is something like this:

```
public class ObjectDataAccess
{
    public static SObject[] queryObjects(ObjectTypeEnum typ, Id[] ids)
    {
        if (typ == ObjectTypeEnum.CAR) ...
        else if (typ == ObjectTypeEnum.BOAT) ...
        else if (typ == ObjectTypeEnum.PART) ...
        else throw error;
    }

    public static SObject[] queryObjects(ObjectTypeEnum typ, String[] uniqeIds)
    {
        if (typ == ObjectTypeEnum.CAR) ...
        else if (typ == ObjectTypeEnum.BOAT) ...
        else throw error;
    }

    public static SObject[] queryAllObjects(...)
    {
        // NO CLUE!
    }
}
```

To me this doesn't look right at all. First, this is more of a Util class than anything else! Second, as you can see I have no idea how to handle the different input/output types for the selectAllObjects method.

All ideas for a proper implementation of this problem are welcome.

Comment: It's not super clear to me what you're actually asking. Also, why did you untag `[apex]`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I have a set of static classes that I would like to call through a single medium. My apologies for the confusion. The Apex tag was initially there because I was thinking of Apex Enterprise Patterns. But I figured it may be redundant because most questions in SFSE are Apex related.

Comment: I still think you leave too much to the imagination for this question to be effectively possible to answer. Maybe if you expanded `...` into `/*quick description of what is going on*/` that might help at least.

Comment: The `...` is a placeholder for the appropriate DAL method call. For example if type = BOAT the `BoatDataAccess.queryBoats(...)` method is called.

Comment: In the `queryAllObjects`, is the desired result where you get the object and it's related objects? Like for example if you queried Account, you'd get Accounts with Contacts, etc. ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ProgrammableMedley no. I just kept them separate for now. I've found that these design challenges become simpler with iteration, so I've left room for a future revisit.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at how the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library does it. Or just use that library; why reinvent the wheel? It allows you to do things like:

```
// In Service Layer
public static Select.Filter isAccountTask()
{
    return Select.Field.startsWith(Task.WhatId, SObjectType.Account.getKeyPrefix());
}

// In Handler Layer
List<Task> accountTasks = TaskService.isAccountTask().filter(newRecords);
```

In this case, it seems like you might wish to filter a generic `List<SObject>` to get the records of a specific type? You might want something like:

```
public Select.Filter isSObjectType(SObjectType schemaType)
{
    return Select.Field.startsWith('Id', schemaType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
}
```

Comment: You know, this post helped me realize I should have probably said Data Access Layer instead of Selector because I am not needing all the features of the Selector library.